# How to make searchbox actually search

Tags: html, css

hi i cant get my searchbox to search my Wordpress site
original css - https://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/ABeIi

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.example.com/">        
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search | Here">               
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your search form to "submit", you need a submit button/input. **However** - this will not "search your wordpress site" automatically, depending on what is being searched for you will need to either:

**Process the search on the server**

write a script that handles capturing the search request, querying the database, and returning the results of the search to the user.

**Process the search client side**

write a script that handles capturing the search request, and use javascript to check your webpage for matching results.

Normally wordpress sites have search functionality included with most themes.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.example.com/">        
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search | Here">               
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Also need to add `name="s"` to the search input, as it will pass a query string to the URL and WordPress default search is `http://www.example.com/?s=term`